# ADD Glyphicons using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I wanna add glyphicon using angular but it can't be done, so what's the problem on my code ?

[image: Problem Code]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jquery and popper, in order to use it with bootstrap

```
 npm install --save jquery
 npm install --save popper
```

But as far as I know, you have to pay to use glyphicons, you could use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here. You have installed `glyphicon` successfully and it should be listed in `package.json` dependencies.

NPM is complaining about some vulnerabilities found in the dependencies versions used in the project. You can run `npm audit fix` to fix the problems. It will install the stable and secure versions of the dependencies.

> **npm audit** is a new command that performs a moment-in-time security review of your project's dependency tree.
>
> Audit reports contain information about security vulnerabilities in
>   your dependencies and can help you fix a vulnerability by providing
>   simple-to-run npm commands and recommendations for further
>   troubleshooting

**Include in your app**

```
// require
var icons = require('glyphicons')

// import
import icons from 'glyphicons'
```